# printer keeps asking for date and time when turned on

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I've got a Samsung MF2070FW printer that keeps asking for date and time every time its turned on. The firmware version is the V3.00.01.37 (the latest) and i tried to search for something like a CMOS battery on the printer motherboard, but with no success.
What can it be?

UPDATE

As suggested by @DrMoishe Pippik the battery is under the printer display PCB, here a picture I took:

[MF2070FW LCD screen PCB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbQYj.jpg)

I'll try to change it in the next days

Comment: Do a hard reset .........  https://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-m2070fw/

Comment: They're typically referred to as a CMOS battery

Comment: @Arctiic you're right, I wasn't accurate

Comment: @John unfortunately an hard reset doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Service Manual](https://kupdf.net/download/samsung-sl-m2070-service-manual_5aa309c3e2b6f52e12af9dd8_pdf), "Lithium battery not replaceable by user."

That said, I personally would try to find it myself and replace it with a similar lithium cell or battery, since I'm comfortable with electronic repairs. **Caveat: An error could lead to electric shock and/or the destruction of the printer.**

A search on Yandex found this image, which *appears* to show a lithium coin cell under the printer display PCB. No guarantee that matches the locations on you printer -- *please* edit this answer, or post a comment, on the accuracy of that image.

[image: Possible Li cell in printer]

BTW, it is usually is far easier to clip wires for a cell soldered in place, *close to the cell*, and solder leads from the new cell to those stubs, observing polarity, than it is to desolder from a multilayer PCB!

Comment: If soldering leads versus de-soldering the old CMOS battery, and the old CMOS battery isn't rechargeable, buying a laptop CMOS battery might be preferred since all that would need to be done is the connector cut off the end, wires stripped, tin the ends of the wires, and solder to the requisite points on the PCB. Laptop CMOS batteries usually come with a protective layer encapsulating the entire battery, but if not, wrap in Super 33+ electrical tape _(the adhesive of Super 33+ doesn't degrade over time like cheaper electrical tape, which over years will dry up with the tape becoming brittle)_

Comment: @JW0914, 1. The clock battery is usually *not* rechargeable. 2. Current drain is low; virtually *any* battery of the same voltage would work. 3. Look at the photo: the battery appears to be mounted on the side **opposite** the conductors. The *old* battery needs to be removed (clipped off) lest it be a short circuit, quickly killing the new one, and wires attached to the same side of the PCB, so that it can be put back in place.